# Help required with SQLs

Tags: sql

I am trying to join 2 tables and trying to fetch the records, which do not have values in the join column of the 2nd table.
For example:
Table 1 Id column values:
1,
**2,**
3,
**4,**

Table 2 Id column values:
1,
3,

Given the above example of the values in the join columns of the 2 tables, I want to fetch **records from table1 with ids 2 and 4**, because they are not present in table2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

My SQL has gotten rusty to the introduction of JPA frameworks, but today I cannot run away from not knowing it, it seems :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.id
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id NOT IN (SELECT id from table2)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks that was fairly simple :), I really need to brush up my query language.

Comment: Beware of NULLs in the ID column in table2, when using a `NOT IN` clause.

Comment: This is likely to be the wrost performing of the possibilities, As always test all fothem to see.

Comment: meh, http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/

Always test your query performance on your data and your server.

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS variant:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT NULL from table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.id)
```